# Passing Activity object to static class

Tags: android, exception, android-activity, static

I have different Activities where the catch{} block mostly should do the same, eg. show a Toast message, finish() the app, or something else. So I made one static class to handle them. It works till now, but I want to know that it's save.

To finish an Activity I have to call finish() which is in the Activity class, so I have to pass it.

I made a static function like this:

```
public static void handleException(Exception e, Context c, Activity a) {

  // handle the exception, for example if there is an authorisation error:

  a.finish();

}
```

In a catch{} block I do the following: (in this case Activity LoginActivity)

```
 ExceptionHandler.handleException(e, _context, (Activity) LoginActivity.this);
```

Is this appropriate? Or does this cause memory leaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont save any link to `Context` or `Activity` there will not be any memory leaks or problems with GC.